# How to mathematically model a realistic aperture illumination?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, fourier-transform, electrical-engineering, antennas

I want to know a mathematical expression that I can use to model a realistic aperture illumination to produce the primary beam of an antenna so that the radial distribution of this aperture illumination will be flat across the beam and only begins to fall off close to the edges of the dish. currently, I try to compose a function like that by using a boxcar for most of the beams and then switch over to a Gaussian as I get towards the edge but my model looks under illuminated, thus, i barely use the surface of the dish. Can anyone help me address this problem?

Comment: Why can't you just turn up the intensity? What makes you think that the problem is with the shape of the distribution?